# Proving $x_1y_1 +x_2y_2 + kx_1y_2 + kx_2y_1$ defines a scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $|k|$ <1

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry

> Prove $x_1y_1 +x_2y_2 + kx_1y_2 + kx_2y_1$ defines a scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $\left|k\right|<1$

Using definition that scalar product is a bilinear function which satisfies linearity, symmetry and positive definiteness

Comment: Hi Crasious, welcome to stackexchange. What have you tried yourself to solve this? Also what do you mean with $|K|$?

Comment: Where 1> |k| sorry. I have thought of different possible ways to solve this but i can't even seem to begin i thought of transpose of x multipled by a matrix A by y but i don't see how k comes into account @FlorisClaassens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that 
$$\langle x,y\rangle_{k}=x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+kx_{1}y_{2}+kx_{2}y_{1}$$
is an inner product we have to show three things. For all $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ we have:

1) $\langle x,y\rangle_{k}=\langle y,x\rangle_{k}$.

2) $\langle \lambda x,y\rangle_{k}=\lambda\langle x,y\rangle_{k}$ and $\langle x+y,z\rangle_{k}=\langle x,z\rangle_{k}+\langle y,z\rangle_{k}$.

3) $\langle x,x\rangle_{k}\geq0$ and $\langle x,x\rangle_{k}=0$ if and only if $x=0$.

1) is obvious from the definition. For 2) note that 
$$\langle \lambda x,y\rangle_{k}=\lambda x_{1}y_{1}+\lambda x_{2}y_{2}+\lambda kx_{1}y_{2}+\lambda kx_{2}y_{1}=\lambda\langle x,y\rangle_{k}$$
and 
$$\langle x+y,z\rangle_{k}=(x_{1}+y_{1})z_{1}+(x_{2}+y_{2})z_{2}+k(x_{1}+y_{1})z_{2}+k(x_{2}+y_{2})z_{1}$$
$$=x_{1}z_{1}+x_{2}z_{2}+kx_{1}z_{2}+kx_{2}z_{1}+y_{1}z_{1}+y_{2}z_{2}+ky_{1}z_{2}+ky_{2}z_{1}=\langle x,z\rangle_{k}+\langle y,z\rangle_{k}$$
and finally by Cauchy-Schwarz we have that $|\langle x,(x_{2},x_{1})\rangle|=|x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}x_{1}|\leq x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}$, hence
$$\langle x,x\rangle_{k}=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+kx_{1}x_{2}+kx_{2}x_{1}\geq x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}-|k||x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}x_{1}|$$
$$\geq x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}-|k|(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2})=(1-|k|)(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2})\geq0$$
with equality if and only if $x_{1}=x_{2}=0$. Note that it is in the last step where we use that $|k|<1$.

Comment: So I presume if |k| >= 1 then it is not defined right? Thanks for your help! Made it a lot clearer  now than before

Comment: If $|k|\geq 1$, then the bilinear function $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{k}$ is still defined, but it is no longer positive semi-definite as $\langle (1,-1),(1,-1)\rangle_{k}=2-2k\leq0$ for $k\geq 1$ and $\langle (1,1),(1,1)\rangle_{k}=2+2k\leq0$ for $k\leq 1$.